# Why does the control key no longer work when selecting text in a Parallels virtual machine?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, osx-mountain-lion, parallels

In Windows 8, the control key is helpful for navigating and selecting text. Ctrl-arrow skips words, and ctrl-shift-arrow selects a word at a time.

I created a Win 8 virtual machine using Parallels 8 on my Mac (Mountain Lion), and the control-arrow text behavior does not work in the VM. It’s very inconvenient and unexpected. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

The Mac captures the control-arrow keystrokes for navigating between work spaces in Mission Control; thus they don’t get passed to the VM.

You can change this by going to the Mac’s System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts, expand the “Mission Control” option, and de-select the checkboxes for “Move left a space” and “Move right a space”. This solved the problem for me.